# How to use artifactoryPublish to publish release and debug artifacts

Tags: android, maven, gradle, artifactory

I have Android Studio projects that build AARs or APKs in both release and debug versions. I'd like to publish these to different to different repositories on my Artifactory server. The [JFrog examples](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples) don't appear to cover this case.

Does this mean that it's considered best practice to simply build either only the release or only the debug version, and choose what and where to upload based on the type of build?

Comment: when dealing with release and snaphot artifacts, you can specify where they are deployed in your settings.xml and make a few small changes in your artifactory instance. I configured mine some time back though i can't remember off head. Just pointing out if you are not ware of this as well?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: The solution proposed by @cooperok looks good to me. I haven't tried it yet, but that's what I was trying to achieve. To paraphrase Captain Mal, "my days of disliking gradle and groovy are coming to a middle."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I configured my android library build.gradle file that compiled aar file  could be uploaded in different repos, dependent on build type.
For example you want to publish debug artifats to 'libs-debug-local' repository and release artifacts to 'libs-release-local' repository.

```
//First you should configure all artifacts you want to publish
publishing {
    publications {

        //Iterate all build types to make specific 
        //artifact for every build type
        android.buildTypes.all { variant ->

            //it will create different 
            //publications ('debugAar' and 'releaseAar')
            "${variant.name}Aar"(MavenPublication) {
                def manifestParser = new com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser()

                //Set values from Android manifest file
                groupId manifestParser.getPackage(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
                version = manifestParser.getVersionName(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
                artifactId project.getName()

                // Tell maven to prepare the generated "*.aar" file for publishing
                artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-${variant.name}.aar")
            }
        }
    }
}

//After configuring publications you should
//create tasks to set correct repo key
android.buildTypes.all { variant ->

    //same publication name as we created above
    def publicationName = "${variant.name}Aar"

    //new task name
    def taskName = "${variant.name}Publication"

    //in execution time setting publications and repo key, dependent on build type
    tasks."$taskName" << {
        artifactoryPublish {
            doFirst {
                publications(publicationName)
                clientConfig.publisher.repoKey = "libs-${variant.name}-local"
            }
        }
    }

    //make tasks assembleDebug and assembleRelease dependent on our new tasks
    //it helps to set corrent values for every task
    tasks."assemble${variant.name.capitalize()}".dependsOn(tasks."$taskName")
}

//Inside artifactory block just set url and credential, without setting repo key and publications
artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://artifactory.cooperok.com:8081/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            username = "username"
            password = "password"
        }
        defaults {
            publishArtifacts = true

            // Properties to be attached to the published artifacts.
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
        }
    }
}
```

That's all. Now if you run command

Win : gradlew assembleRelease artifactoryPublish
   Mac : ./gradlew assembleRelease artifactoryPublish

aar file will be uploaded to 'libs-release-local' repository.
And if you ran

Win : gradlew assembleDebug artifactoryPublish
   Mac : ./gradlew assembleDebug artifactoryPublish

it will be uploaded to 'libs-debug-local' repository

One minus of this configuration is that you should always run artifactoryPublish task with assembleDebug/Release tasks

Comment: That's the approach I was looking for. Thanks, @cooperok!

Comment: This works well alongside information @ http://jeroenmols.github.io/blog/2015/08/06/artifactory/

Comment: @keno I started to use Artifactory after reading that post, also there is my comment about generating pom.xml

Comment: @cooperok, I get an error from gradle on the line `tasks."$taskName" <<` that says `Could not find property 'debugPublication' on task set.`. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @keno I had the same error while building application which was depended on library, I fixed it by adding value `android {  publishNonDefault true ...}` inside library project

Comment: @keno   I think you should replaced "**tasks."$taskName"** with **"task "$taskName""**

Comment: IMHO instead of 'tasks."assemble${variant.name.capitalize()}".dependsOn(tasks."$taskName")' it should be the other way around: 'tasks."$taskName".dependsOn(tasks."assemble${variant.name.capitalize()}")'

Answer (score 3):

try this:-

```
def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            if ('assembleRelease' in runTasks)
                repoKey = "${artifactory_repository_release}"
            else if ('assembleDebug' in runTasks)
                repoKey = "${artifactory_repository_debug}"

            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            publishArtifacts = true
            if ('assembleRelease' in runTasks)
                publications("${artifactory_publication_release}")
            else if ('assembleDebug' in runTasks)
                publications("${artifactory_publication_debug}")
            publishPom = true
            publishIvy = false
        }
    }
}
```

where artifactory_repository_release=libs-release-local and artifactory_repository_debug=libs-debug-local

artifactory repo on which you want to publish your library arr.

Answer (score 2):

After a gradle update to '**com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.x.x**'
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32356445/4291264) no longer works for me.

My final solution was:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = ARTIFACTORY_URL
    //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            File debugFile = new File("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${SDK_NAME}-debug.aar");
            if ( debugFile.isFile() )
                repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local'
            else
                repoKey = 'libs-release-local'

            username = ARTIFACTORY_USER
            password = ARTIFACTORY_PWD
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            File debugFile = new File("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${SDK_NAME}-debug.aar");
            if ( debugFile.isFile() )
                publications("debugAar")
            else
                publications("releaseAar")

            publishArtifacts = true
            // Properties to be attached to the published artifacts.
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            // Is this even necessary since it's TRUE by default?
            // Publish generated POM files to Artifactory (true by default)
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        //Iterate all build types to make specific
        //artifact for every build type
        android.buildTypes.all {variant ->
            //it will create different
            //publications ('debugAar' and 'releaseAar')
            "${variant.name}Aar"(MavenPublication) {
                writeNewPom(variant.name)
                groupId GROUP_NAME
                artifactId SDK_NAME
                version variant.name.endsWith('debug') ? VERSION_NAME + "-SNAPSHOT" : VERSION_NAME
                // Tell maven to prepare the generated "*.aar" file for publishing
                artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${SDK_NAME}-${variant.name}.aar")
            }
        }
    }
}

def writeNewPom(def variant) {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId GROUP_NAME
            artifactId SDK_NAME
            version variant.endsWith('debug') ? VERSION_NAME + "-SNAPSHOT" : VERSION_NAME
            packaging 'aar'

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }.withXml {
        def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

        configurations.api.allDependencies.each {dependency ->
            if (dependency.group != null) {
                def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dependency.group)
                dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dependency.name)
                dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dependency.version)
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("$buildDir/publications/${variant}Aar/pom-default.xml")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do complex Groovy code to achieve this.  I have this for the project build.gradle:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'https://artifactory.test.com/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-testing-local'
            username = artifactory_username
            password = artifactory_password
        }
        defaults {
            publications('debugAar')
            publications('releaseAar')
            publishArtifacts = true

            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'q.os': 'android', 'dev.team': 'core']
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

This is my module build.gradle:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        android.buildTypes.all { variant ->
            "${variant.name}Aar"(MavenPublication) {
                groupId libraryGroupId
                version libraryVersion
                artifactId "library-${variant.name}"

                artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/library-${variant.name}.aar")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A key to note here, whatever you put in the project build.gradle's artifactory.publish.defaults, under publications() has to match the module build.gradle's loop: "${variant.name}Aar"(MavenPublication).

Another thing is you also set the artifactory_username and artifactory_password 
(encrypted version from Artifactory) in ~/.gradle/gradle/gradle.properties.

Comment: not quite, in your solution you always have to publish all variants, what if you only want to publish debug on CI or only release?

Answer (score 0):

For snapshots + release versions, you can use sonatype (aka mavencentral). I did up a short guide couple of weeks back which you might find of some use. [How to publish Android AARs - snapshots/release to Mavencentral](https://github.com/omgnuts/android-aar-startkit)

Answer (score 0):

Can't get publishing work with @cooperok answer otherwise it help me alots.

Here is my code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
    }

    publishNonDefault true

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
        }
        snapshot {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
        }
    }

}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath +=    project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}

publishing {
    publications {
        android.buildTypes.all { variant ->
            "${variant.name}"(MavenPublication) {
                def manifestParser = new com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser()
                groupId manifestParser.getPackage(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
                if("${variant.name}".equalsIgnoreCase("release")){
                    version = manifestParser.getVersionName(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
                }else if ("${variant.name}".equalsIgnoreCase("debug")){
                    version = manifestParser.getVersionName(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile).concat("-${variant.name}".toUpperCase().concat("-SNAPSHOT"))
                }else{
                    version = manifestParser.getVersionName(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile).concat("-${variant.name}".toUpperCase())
                }

                artifactId project.getName()

                artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-${variant.name}.aar")
                artifact androidJavadocsJar

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                    configurations.getByName("_releaseCompile").getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
                        def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                        dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                        dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

android.buildTypes.all { variant ->

    model {
        tasks."generatePomFileFor${variant.name.capitalize()}Publication" {
            destination = file("$buildDir/publications/${variant.name}/generated-pom.xml")
        }
    }

    def publicationName = "${variant.name}"

    def taskName = "${variant.name}Publication"

    task "$taskName"() << {
        artifactoryPublish {
            doFirst {
                tasks."generatePomFileFor${variant.name.capitalize()}Publication".execute()
                publications(publicationName)
                clientConfig.publisher.repoKey = "${variant.name}".equalsIgnoreCase("release") ? "libs-release-local" :
                        "libs-snapshot-local"
            }
        }
    }


    tasks."assemble${variant.name.capitalize()}".dependsOn(tasks."$taskName")

}


artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://172.16.32.220:8081/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            username = "admin"
            password = "password"
        }
        defaults {
            publishPom = true
            publishArtifacts = true
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
artifactory {
        contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
        
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'your repo key'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                mavenCompatible = true

            }
            defaults {
                publications('mavenJava')
                publishBuildInfo = true
                publishArtifacts = true
                publishPom = true
            }


        }
        resolve {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'yourrepokey'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true

            }
        }
    }
    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = "$group"
                artifactId = "$rootProject.name"
                version = "${ver}"
                from components.java
                artifact jar
                artifact javadocJar
                artifact sourcesJar
            }
        }
    }
```